# How to add html content above series(Chart type - line)

Tags: highcharts

How can we add content above every series like a html content .for ex - My Content. I am using line chart.

here is an example which i found in api.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekec5nut/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.text('Series 1', 90, 150)
        .attr({
            rotation: 0
        })
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();

});
});
```

but I do not want to give position like this : chart.renderer.text('Series 1', 90, 150) . I want is to have the content above each series while series are getting created.

Comment: You need to define what is "above serie", in the center of serie or above 3 point? You can get any point coordinates and then add a few pixels, to print text there.

Comment: I want to print above the series where it is drawn not in center. How can i get the position or coordinates where series is getting started.Please help.

Comment: You can get first point form the serie (in this object it contains coordaintes) and use it in renderer.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using dataLabels for first point? Just like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
               {
                   dataLabels: { 
                       enabled: true,  
                       formatter: function() { return 'My Content'; }
                   },
                   y: 29.9
               },
               71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
});
```